# How to access data in list of elements of custom type?

Tags: haskell

There is a data type `Ticket` with four attributes and then i created `Trip` that is a list of `Ticket`s. I want to check if a trip is valid by checking if for any consecutive tickets the destination city of the first ticket is same as the departure for the second ticket.

```hs
data Ticket = Ticket {
    typeBilhete :: String
    , typeClass :: String
    , cityOrin :: String
    , cityDestination :: String
} deriving (Show)

data Trip = Trip [Ticket]

validTrip :: [Bilhete] -> Bool
validTrip b = 
    if head b == "Recife" = then True
    else False
```

My problem is to how access elements like `cityOrigin` and `cityDestination`? so i can compare then in `validTrip` func.

Comment: That's not a list of types.

Answer (score 2):

An empty or singleton list is clearly valid:

```
validTrip :: [Ticket] -> Bool
validTrip [] = True
validTrip [_] = True
```

With two or more tickets, the trip is valid if the first and second tickets "fit", and the rest of the list is also valid.

```
validTrip (x:y:rest) = cityDestination x == cityOrin y && validTrip (y:rest)
```

`cityDestination` and `cityOrin` are both simply functions of type `Ticket -> String`.

Answer (score 1):

It's a simple one-liner:

```
validTrip :: [Ticket] -> Bool
validTrip b = 
    and [ cityDestination t == cityOrigin t2 | (t,t2) <- zip b (drop 1 b)]
```